# Delphi XE 5 Application Not Starting up from startup Directory Windows 8.1

Tags: windows, delphi

I am trying to get my application to start at startup. So far i have tested it on windows xp and windows 7 and it works like a charm. But in windows 8.1 the shortcut is in the startup directory `C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Roaming\Microsoft\Windows\Start Menu\Programs\Startup` but it does not start.

If i check with the task manager under the start up tab the application is there and is enabled. But it just doesn't start on start up.

Can anybody please assist?

**Update 1:**

I have found the problem. I marked the application to run as administrator. When i removed that privileges the application started at start up. Why would this interfere? i ran it as administrator in windows 7. and since have tested it on windows 8 and also had to set it to run as administrator, even then it worked. Only in 8.1 did it cause the software not to start up.

Does anybody know why?

**UPDATE 2:**

OK to be clearer on the above mentioned update. and comments.

The program works fine. Nothing is wrong with it.
When it is checked to run as administrator it does not auto start. When the admin rights are removed. It does auto start.

I have done a simple test to see if the software even launches and it does not so logging wont help. I set a message to appear if the application launches so before anything is processed i get notified. Before there can be any errors in code it will tell me.

SO the problem is not the coding in the program. The problem clearly is windows 8.1 which does not let my application auto launch on start up when it has admin rights.

Comment: Why not HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run

Comment: I have tried that also. I run copy on my computer. it is also in the HKLU\Software\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Run where i inserted it in regedit.exe and neither method works. It just doesnt start. While the other applications does start.

Comment: HKLM presumably. It does work. Guess there's a problem with your program. Time for you to do some debugging. Try a vanilla app work from there to the real app

Comment: i have just added a couple of items. Some of which are apps i developed for testing ect. And also apps developed by other companies. They all started. While my application was in the list with them, it was the only one that did not start. This same application 3 days ago started automatically on windows 7 before i upgraded. nothing in it has changed. Is there anything in windows that could be blocking its auto-launch?

Comment: Try doing some debugging.

Comment: Bottom line appears to be that there is a problem with your program. Since only you can see it, only you can solve it.

Comment: If not debugging, at least some log file recording start and close. And if there is no close record you have failure of some kind.

Comment: As a workaround you may create a task in the Task Scheduler with your program and configure it to run on user login (or startup, check the options)

Comment: Does the application start if you try to run it by clicking on the shortcut. If not check the wokring directory setting of the shortcut. If it dies then your program might relly on some windows service or COM interface that still isn't initialized at the time. In such case you might wanna use some delayed startup of your application in order to give necessary services or COM objects to be initialized first.

Comment: @silverwarior Yes the application does start if i manually start it. Which is why i cannot understand why it does not start with autostart. On other operating systems i have had no problems. How do you delay the startup to allow other apps to start first?

Comment: @user3510818 I don't understand why you won't debug your problem by adding logging. Take this as an opportunity to learn some problem solving skills.

Comment: Probably MS decided not to show UAC dialogs for startup programs. There is no problem with Windows 8.1, you just have to accept that it won't present users with UAC dialogs for autorun programs, a most sensible choice.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It transpires that the issue is that you wish the program to run elevated which results in a UAC dialog being shown. Windows blocks autostart programs that requested elevation. You report a difference between Windows 7 and Windows 8 but I suspect that the real difference is your UAC settings on the two machines.

This is discussed in more detail in these links:

- https://superuser.com/questions/536990/run-as-administrator-prevents-applications-from-autostart
- http://botsikas.blogspot.co.uk/2010/05/autostart-application-that-requires-uac.html
- http://www.sevenforums.com/installation-setup/182612-getting-programs-run-startup-uac.html
- http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/make-vista-launch-uac-restricted-programs-at-startup-with-task-scheduler/

In all cases, the recommendation is to use the task scheduler to cache admin credentials and so avoid facing the UAC dialog.

Comment: No David in windows XP, 7 and 8 it works fine with the elevation. only windows 8.1 blocks it.

But either way. How do i use the task scheduler to accomplish this task?

Comment: Instructions can be found by following the links. They also state that Vista blocks autostart programs that need elevation. Would be surprising if they blocked in Vista, allowed in 7 and 8, and then blocked again in 8.1. Are you sure you have same UAC settings on all OS? Also XP is irrelevant since there is no UAC.